# I need pointers for cross-browser css issues

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I'm having trouble with the header of this website: http://jenn.anniezs.com/enzo_demo/

It works fine in Firefox, but it's a disaster in Chrome and Safari. Unfortunately, I do not know these browsers very well, I'm still learning them.

I think it might have something to do with the positioning or float, but I can't pin-point it.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`float: center` does not exist. Take this out and all you have are some spacing issues causing your last menu item to drop below the rest.

```
#primary-menu ul li.button {
...
float: center;/*No, use float:left or take this out entirely*/
...
}
```